# Codeigniter creating ci_session by default

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am new to codeigniter. I created one application with codeigniter. The issue here is when i load my index page it is creating two cookies those were

```
ci_session

PHPSESSID
```

Is any one knows how these cookies were being created and the purpose of the these cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The `ci_session` is set as default session Cookie name in config.php in config folder. you can overwrite the name to something else. CI use this name to store all the session/cookie data inside this variable.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
```

PHPSESSID is defined in your PHP ini file like below to store cookie in browser:

```
session.name = PHPSESSID
```

You can get more information about this: http://php.net/session.name

Comment: Yeah but i didn't created any session to get these cookies. Is these were being created automatically??

Comment: what exactly you want to do? Is there any problem with cookie? just google it as why web pages use cookie.

Comment: Yeah i know how cookies would be used but I am creating an website about cookies thats why i need to know why these cookies were created and the purpose of those cookies

Answer (score 0):

look in your `application/config/autoload.php` file and check if the Session class is being enabled by default.

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array(); this is the statement i'm having

Comment: add session in the array like $autoload['libraries'] = array('session');